# Hibernate querying unmapped tables

Tags: hibernate, object

Is there a way to use java bean functionality on unmapped tables?

So, I have a table that is used only for reads, it will never be modified. I need to query it to only to display data. But I don't want the Object [] return type that hibernate defaults to when querying unmapped objects. I want to retrieve the results into a custom typed collection. But I will have to create the hbm file to do this. Is there anyway to just create the custom type and no hbm file?

Businessobj method that loads the results:

```
loadResults()
{
    String qry = "select col1, col2 from table";                
    List<CustomType> result = (ArrayList<CustomType>) dao.HQLWithTransformer(qry, new CustomTransformer()); 
}
```

Custom transformer:

```
public class CustomTransformer implements ResultTransformer {



@Override
public Object transformTuple(Object[] rowdata, String[] arg1) 
{       

        return new CustomType(String.valueOf(rowdata[0]),String.valueOf(rowdata[1]));

    return null;
}

@Override
public List transformList(List arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

DAO method:

```
public Collection HQLWithTransformer(String qry, ResultTransformer rt){     

    List<?> al=null;
      try
      {            
       Query q = sess.createQuery(qry);
       q.setResultTransformer(rt);
       al = (ArrayList<?>)q.list();                   
      }
      catch(HibernateException he) 
      {       
      log.debug("Hibernate Exception", he);
      }
      finally 
      {
        sess.close();        
      }

    return al;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use constructor expressions, like this:

```
List<MyClass> dtos = session.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.MyClass( e.name, e.data) FROM Entity e").list();
```

The downside is that you would also have to create the `Entity`, mapping the table in order to query for it. You can do it with annotations, so you won't have to create a `hbm` file.

Technically, it is not quite what you asked for. I have found it useful for mapping report-like queries though, so perhaps it is what you are looking for.

Comment: tried the annotations. For some reason the annotations are not being recognized. My classpath has hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, hibernate3.jar(3.5),hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar.

Comment: I was able to figure out why the annotations were not working. Had some setup issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NativeCriteria library ([Project on github, available on maven central](https://github.com/pnowy/NativeCriteria)). Example code is looking like below:

```
NativeCriteria c = new NativeCriteria(new HibernateQueryProvider(hibernateSession), "table_name", "alias");
c.setProjection(NativeExps.projection().addProjection("alias.column_name"));  
c.add(NativeExps.isNull("alias.column_name"));
c.setOrder(NativeExps.order().add("alias.column_name", OrderType.ASC));
CriteriaResult res = c.criteriaResult();
while (res.next())
{
    resp.add(res.getLong(0, null));
}
```

[Offical page](http://pnowy.github.io/NativeCriteria/) of library. This library based on hibernate session and createSQLQuery but provide very clean and simple API to generate dynamic and complicated queries which does't have equivalent as mapped class.

You could see more examples (and integration with Spring / Spring Boot) on the test module.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [`ResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) for your query.

Hibernate provides various transformers that can convert query results to unmapped types. For example, [AliasToBeanResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html) performs conversion based on aliases of selected fields.

Comment: created a custom transformer. my code in the OP. I still see the table not mapped error.

Comment: Non-mapped tables can be queried only with SQL queries, not HQL queries. Use `createSQLQuery()`.